# use a collection with simple form causes error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

when I true to use a custom collection select using simple form I get an error, and error i dont get if i use constants.

This works...

```
  = f.input :timing, collection: JobDeliveryCost::TIMINGS, :include_blank => "please select"
```

and this doesn't work

```
  = f.input :delivery_cost_id, collection: DeliveryCost.order(:title), :id, :title
```

giving this error

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
```

what gives?! I tried switching it up a little

```
  = f.input :delivery_cost_id, :collection => DeliveryCost.order(:title), :id, :title
```

which still gives this error,

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
```

It's mega confusing. Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `f.input` method as the following:

```
f.input :delivery_cost_id, collection: DeliveryCost.order(:title), :label_method => :title,:value_method => :id
```

---

## The following is not the cause of the error but might be interesting for some users

This is a typical Ruby syntax error:

```
= f.input :delivery_cost_id, collection: DeliveryCost.order(:title), :id, :title
```

Should be:

```
= f.input :delivery_cost_id, { collection: DeliveryCost.order(:title) }, :id, :title
```

---

**Why?!** Because Ruby's interpretation of the code implies that every last arguments are Hash, example:

```
User.new(name: 'bob', last_name: 'Bob Marley')
# is strictly equivalent to
User.new({ name: 'bob', last_name: 'Bob Marley' })
```

But you cannot do the following:

```
User.new(name: 'bob', last_name: 'Bob Marley', 150)
```

It breaks the Ruby's interpreter, it does not know what to do with the trailing `, 150)`. For the code above (which does not make really make sense), you should do:

```
User.new({ name: 'bob', last_name: 'Bob Marley' }, 150)
```

This way, Ruby knows that the first argument is a Hash, and the second is an Integer.

Comment: I had tried that, but that gave this error:

wrong number of arguments (4 for 1..2)

Comment: @Yoshi, those explanations are awesome, you deserve points maximum for that. plus you've saved my bacon a lot this week.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, I appreciate that! Have fun with Rails ;)